# MySQL fulltext/regexp/levenshtein search optimization

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, full-text-search

I have a database of 100+ million records (and rapidly growing) and I would like to implement a search feature that sorts by the closest results.
I did some research and found that fulltext searches are only prefixes, which isn't really what I want.

I got results that are close enough to call it good, but the problem is the query is very slow.

The levenshtein function is from here: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=552

Here's the query:

```
SELECT `id`, 
       `word`, 
        MATCH (`word`) AGAINST ('+*search*') IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `match` 
FROM `words` 
WHERE `word` REGEXP '^.*[search].*$' 
  AND levenshtein(`word`, 'search') <= 2 
ORDER BY levenshtein(`word`, 'search'), `match` ASC 
LIMIT 10;
```

So, overall the results are pretty close, but it takes minutes to actually complete the search, which is really not what I want since each time a key is pressed I send a jquery AJAX request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've used http://sphinxsearch.com/ pretty successfully in the past (admittedly not for 100m+ records, but it was fast enough that I don't think it would give you a problem). You can tweak the weighting of different components to ensure you get the 'correct' results

Comment: `[search]` is searching for an `s`, `e`, `a`, `r`, `c`, or `h`. Is that your intent? I think `WHERE \`word\` like '%search%'` would suffice (if you are trying to just see if `search` is present in the column).

Comment: @chris85 That was somewhat the intent, yes. %search% wasn't giving me results that were an approximation of "search" (like "s34rch") - that made the whole exercise sort of pointless since that was the purpose of having the levenshtein function

Comment: @RobGudgeon I started looking into sphinx search. It seems like that's what I'm looking for, but I also don't want to cause yet more load on the sever by needing to update two databases.

Comment: The cronjob to keep the sphinx indexes up to date is pretty quick & shouldn't cause your server much grief

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using [sphinxsearch](http://www.sphinxsearch.com) as @RobGudgeon suggested. Though not MySQL (and another database on its own) it's actually very quick on both updating from MySQL and searching within its own database. Recommended for fulltext searches on big databases since MySQL's native support is currently lacking.